# Is there any full-featured open source music streaming server out there?

Tags: streaming, red5, icecast

I need a music stream server with at least these features:
1- open source
2- adaptive bitrate
3- multi-art support
4- scalable
5- simple encryption

I have installed some projects (Red, Mopidy, Icecast, ...) but til now I couldn't find a suitable one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any server like that too (let me know if you will find one:) ), but in general everything can be built at the top of Icecast:

1. It's open source
2. This is usually achieved by creating several mount points with different bitrate,and providing your listeners with several links
   they can choose the bitrate (or format, like mp3/aac) that will fit
   their internet connection.
3. Create a script in PHP or any other language that will fetch the current artist & track title from Icecast and search for an image on
   a music service like iTunes or Spotify (they have API for that). Some
   source clients also provide images from MP3 tags, for example.
4. You can use Nginx as a load balancer in front of your Icecast instances, also there is a nice article about that
   https://medium.com/@pereiragoncalo/icecast-in-production-7313cb5c95ff#.m4bf6yne7
5. Not sure what exact encryption you are talking about, but Icecast supports SSL, so you can have HTTPS links to your streams.